# What happened to pg_xlog?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-10, write-ahead-logging

There uesd to be a directory called `pg_xlog` that stored all of the WAL logs in PostgreSQL? Part of restoring a basebackup under the archiving scheme required me to copy the WAL into `DATA_DIR/pg_xlog`. What happened to this directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## PostgreSQL 10+

In PostgreSQL 10 the WAL directory was renamed from `pg_xlog` to the easier to remember `pg_wal`.

- [Pg 10: WAL Internals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/wal-internals.html) (you can click the top for 9.6 to see the older version before the docs were updated to reflect the change).
- [New in postgres 10: Renaming of "xlog" to "wal" Globally (and location/lsn)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Renaming_of_.22xlog.22_to_.22wal.22_Globally_.28and_location.2Flsn.29) describes the change in more details.